# Convert list to array in java in another class

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code and I am new to this project so help me out this:

```
private List<DbParam> getCorrespondingDbParams(Map<String, Object> source, boolean continueOnKeyAbsent, CMetaBasicField...fields){
    List<DbParam> dbParams = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CMetaBasicField field : fields) {
        String key = field.getKey();
        if (!source.containsKey(key)) {
            if(continueOnKeyAbsent){
                continue;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        dbParams.add(field.getDbParam(source.get(key)));
    }
    return dbParams;
}
```

and when dbParams go to getDbParam is type of List

```
default DbParam getDbParam(Object val) {
    return new DbParam(new DbColumn(getDbField(), getFieldType()),val);
}
```

But I want to convert in array. How to do this?

Comment: here getDbParam is type of list but i want to convert it to array

Comment: Please try to explain yourself a little better. DbParam is a class and the return value type of getDbParam. So getDbParam ist not really a list but a DbParam. So I don't understand what you're trying to say. What exactly do you want to convert into an array? If you want the getDbParam method to return an array, then you need to supply the code of your DbParam class, because unless we know what's in there, there's no way we would know how to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a arraylist to an array by doing:

```
dbParam[] myArr= new dbParam[myList.size()];
myArr= myList.toArray(myArr);
```

so you should convert your list to arraylist

Comment: i want to convert getDbParam .in as type of array because it getting value in list type but i change to it in array

Comment: It's unclear what you want. getDbParam is  a function, what change do you want in that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting between an ArrayList and an array like this:

```
List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String []myArray = new String[myArrayList.size()];
myArrayList.toArray(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DbParam[] arr = list.toArray(new DbParam[list.size()]);
```

Comment: i wan to change in getDbParam method not in getCorrespondingDbParams method

Comment: @jitendravarshney return new DbParam[] {new DbParam(new DbColumn(getDbField(), getFieldType()),val)};